# Unwanted behaviour from dict.fromkeys

Tags: python

I'd like to initialise a dictionary of sets (in Python 2.6) using `dict.fromkeys`, but the resulting structure behaves strangely. More specifically:

```
>>>> x = {}.fromkeys(range(10), set([]))
>>>> x
{0: set([]), 1: set([]), 2: set([]), 3: set([]), 4: set([]), 5: set([]), 6: set([]), 7: set([]), 8: set([]), 9: set([])}
>>>> x[5].add(3)
>>>> x
{0: set([3]), 1: set([3]), 2: set([3]), 3: set([3]), 4: set([3]), 5: set([3]), 6: set([3]), 7: set([3]), 8: set([3]), 9: set([3])}
```

I obviously don't want to add 3 to all sets, only to the set that corresponds to `x[5]`. Of course, I can avoid the problem by initialising `x` without `fromkeys`, but I'd like to understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: They're all the same set. Sets, lists, dictionaries and any other object are reference types, and when you assign them to another variable, only the reference is copied, not the actual object. `fromkeys` must use assignment to associate the set with each key, but as you can see, this does not copy the set. I'm not sure how to get around this, aside from creating the dictionary in a different way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The second argument to `dict.fromkeys` is just a value.  You've created a dictionary that has the *same* set as the value for every key.  Presumably you understand the way this works:

```
>>> a = set()
>>> b = a
>>> b.add(1)
>>> b
set([1])
>>> a
set([1])
```

you're seeing the same behavior there; in your case, `x[0]`, `x[1]`, `x[2]` (etc) are all different ways to access the exact same `set` object.

This is a bit easier to see with objects whose string representation includes their memory address, where you can see that they're identical:

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(range(2), object())
{0: <object object at 0x1001da080>,
 1: <object object at 0x1001da080>}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do this with a generator expression:

```
x = dict( (i,set()) for i in range(10) )
```

In Python 3, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
x = { i : set() for i in range(10) }
```

In both cases, the expression `set()` is evaluated for each element, instead of being evaluated once and copied to each element.

Comment: +1 for providing the solution even after the accepted answer explained it well.

Comment: If instead of sets I want to initialize lists, x = { i : [] for i in range(10) } causes SyntaxError while the dict( (i,[]) for i in range(10) ) does not.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that dictionary comprehensions work in Python 2.7 and up.

Answer (score 3):

Because of [this](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c?revision=81029&view=markup) from the `dictobject.c`:

```
while (_PyDict_Next(seq, &pos, &key, &oldvalue, &hash))
{
            Py_INCREF(key);
            Py_INCREF(value);
            if (insertdict(mp, key, hash, value))
                return NULL;
}
```

The `value` is your "set([])", it is evaluated only once then their result object reference count is incremented and added to the dictionary, it doesn't evaluates it every time it adds into the dict.

Answer (score 0):

The reason its working this way is that `set([])` creates an object (a set object). Fromkeys then uses that specific object to create all its dictionary entries. Consider:

```
>>> x
{0: set([]), 1: set([]), 2: set([]), 3: set([]), 4: set([]), 5: set([]), 
6: set([]), 7: set([]), 8: set([]), 9: set([])}
>>> x[0] is x[1]
True
```

All the sets are the same!

Comment: You should really be comparing identities: `x[0] is x[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#To do what you want:

import copy
s = set([])
x = {}
for n in range(0,5):
  x[n] = copy.deepcopy(s)
x[2].add(3)
print x

#Printing
#{0: set([]), 1: set([]), 2: set([3]), 3: set([]), 4: set([])}
```

Comment: No need for `deepcopy`. `x[n] = set()` creates a new set for each value.