# Python: Change just one entry in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Basically I just want to change nested dictionaries but in my code I change multiple sublevel dictionaries at once.

So I have a nested dictionary which looks this way

```
d1 = {'a': {0: [1,2], 1: [1,2]}, 'b': {0: [1,2], 1: [1,2]}}
```

Then I want to add an entry

```
d1['a'][2] = [2,2]
```

And then I get what I want

```
{'a': {0: [1, 2], 1: [1, 2], 2: [2, 2]}, 'b': {0: [1, 2], 1: [1, 2]}}
```

But when I want to create my dictionary like this (and I need it that way, because my dict has to have different lengths and so on)

```
d2 = dict.fromkeys(['a','b'], dict.fromkeys([0,1], [1,2]))
```

I will get

```
{'a': {0: [1, 2], 1: [1, 2], 2: [2, 2]}, 'b': {0: [1, 2], 1: [1, 2], 2: [2, 2]}}
```

so it will add the new dictionary entry to both lower level dictionaries. Why does it do this and how can I prevent this? I tried now a lot of stuff but I cant manage to solve this... Maybe you can help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initailizing nested dict with .fromkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574832/initailizing-nested-dict-with-fromkeys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check answers here:

[Unwanted behaviour from dict.fromkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000468/unwanted-behaviour-from-dict-fromkeys)

[If dict().fromkeys() all point to the same object, what purpose does the default value argument serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152939/if-dict-fromkeys-all-point-to-the-same-object-what-purpose-does-the-default)

In particular, if you try:

```
dict.fromkeys(['a','b'], object())
```

you will see that the adresses are the same:

```
{'a': <object at 0x2fa88dfebe0>, 'b': <object at 0x2fa88dfebe0>}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you run `dict.fromkeys(keys, default)` it creates a dictionary with the keys you provided and gives all of them the same default value you provided. Your problem is that the default value you provided is itself a dictionary which is mutable. Because it is mutable it is stored as a reference to one object. When you reference it in two places they are both references to the same object.

You will need to run `dict.copy()` to create a separate copy.

A way of generating a dict that will work for your case is.

```py
d1 = dict.fromkeys([0,1], [1,2])
d2 = {key:d1.copy() for key in ["a", "b"]}
```

But keep in mind you'll now have the same issue one level lower in d1 as the [1,2] lists are all the same list.

Comment: "Because it is mutable it is stored as a reference to one object."  - this has nothing to do with `default` being mutable or not. `dict.fromkeys` always uses the *same* object as value for all keys. The only thing is that you can't have any problem with non mutable objects, as you can't mutate a value, but only replace the value object for a given key by a different object.